# Way to configure notifications/alerts for a kubernetes pod which is reaching 90% memory and which is not exposed to internet(backend microservice)

Tags: kubernetes, alert, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-pod

I am currently working on a solution for alerts/notifications  where we have microservices deployed on kubernetes in a way of frontend and back end services. There has been multiple occasions where backend services are not able to restart or reach a 90% allocated pod limit, if they encounter memory exhaust. To identify such pods we want an alert mechanism to lookin when they fail or saturation level. We have prometheus and grafana as monitoring services but are not able  to configure alerts, as i have quite a limited knowledge in these, however any suggestions and references provided where i can have detailed way on achieving this will be helpful. Please do let me know
I did try it out on the internet for such ,but almost all are pointing to node level ,cluster level monitoring only. :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywqNE.png)

The Query used to check the memory usage is :
sum (container_memory_working_set_bytes{image!="",name=~"^k8s_.*",namespace=~"^$namespace$",pod_name=~"^$deployment-[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+"}) by (pod_name)

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Its your local env or you are using cloud provider. As you are using `Prometheus` and `Grafana` did you check [this docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/create-alerts/) Did you try to use [Prometheus AlertManager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/) ? Pleas share your alert rule.

Comment: Hello PjoterS, We have prometheus to collect the metrics and grafana to visualize dashboard. In grafana we have akubernetes deplyment details (by prometheus) dashboard that has cpu  panel, memory panel which shows consumption for all the pods ~50 pods. i want to set an alert and notification for any pod that memory consumption crosses 85%, notify the members on the resource that is consuming high value with pod details and image. I am able to integrate this alert via microsoft teams. but required result of alert Not achieved .IF this can be achieved in grafana itself?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this recently on google. It might be helpful to you. https://groups.google.com/u/1/g/prometheus-users/c/1n_z3cmDEXE?pli=1

Comment: Hello Raja, Thanks for the response. But these need to be configured in prometheus alert manager itself or in the grafana?